# Sending an order into Quickbooks via IPP doesn't work when transaction date is in the past

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I've edited the question to make it more clean and focused now that I've investigated more.

Syncing orders are working for today's date and future dates, but not for dates in the past.  I'm testing now directly in the API explorer.

Here is the add order request and response:

```
<!--Add order request-->
<Add xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    RequestId="ecc53f53d70f0a52de4c88021721ba32" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 ./RestDataFilter.xsd ">
    <OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId>
    <ExternalRealmId>688875295</ExternalRealmId>
    <Object xsi:type="SalesOrder">
        <Header>
            <DocNumber>6</DocNumber>
            <TxnDate>2010-12-25</TxnDate>
            <CustomerId idDomain="QB">4</CustomerId>
            <SalesRepId idDomain="QB">1</SalesRepId>
        </Header>
        <Line>
            <ItemId idDomain="QB">1</ItemId>
            <Qty>6</Qty>
        </Line>
    </Object>
</Add>

<!--Add order response-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
    <Success RequestId="ecc53f53d70f0a52de4c88021721ba32">
        <ObjectRef>
            <Id idDomain="NG">802721</Id>
            <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
            <LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-29T15:26:53Z</LastUpdatedTime>
        </ObjectRef>
        <RequestName>SalesOrderAdd</RequestName>
        <ProcessedTime>2013-04-29T15:26:53Z</ProcessedTime>
    </Success>
</RestResponse>
```

Here is the sync status and sync activity.  There was only one entity with SalesOrder, but the times don't match up, so I don't believe its referencing the same order that I added via API explorer.  Also, the order that I added did not appear in Quickbooks also.

```
<SyncStatusResponse>
<NgIdSet>
<NgId>802721</NgId>
<NgObjectType>SalesOrder</NgObjectType>
</NgIdSet>
<RequestId>DB7F4BF877006079E040900A0F1B14C1</RequestId>
<StateCode>8</StateCode>
<StateDesc>Record netted with QB</StateDesc>
<MessageCode>70</MessageCode>
<MessageDesc>MBL Netter success using QB SDK ext_ack_id</MessageDesc>
<ResponseLogTMS>2013-04-29T15:38:02.0Z</ResponseLogTMS>
</SyncStatusResponse>


<SyncActivityResponse>
<SyncType>Writeback</SyncType>
<StartSyncTMS>2013-04-10T12:42:21.0</StartSyncTMS>
<EndSyncTMS>2013-04-29T08:38:02.0</EndSyncTMS>
<EntityName>SalesOrder</EntityName>
<EntityRowCount>20</EntityRowCount>
</SyncActivityResponse>
```

From the sync status response, state code 8 means

> Record netted. Synchronized. Object created in Data Services. Sync Manager has acknowledged synchronizing the object and mapped its NG ID to a QB ID in QuickBooks. Equivalent to StateCode 1 (for object created in QuickBooks).

Message code 70 seems to be ok base on its description, but it wasn't listed in the [documentation](http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus).

Comment: Can you post your request and response please?

Comment: Also, if your create request succeeds but it doesnt sync you need to check the sync activity/sync status and make sure it didnt error when syncing.

Comment: @JarredKeneally I added detail to the question. For the sync activity/sync status, do you mean Intuit Sync Manager?  I figured out how to see the log files, and there are 15 log files.  Is this what you're referring to?  (Sorry, I'm brand new to this and development in general).

Comment: The Sync manager is the software that moves data from the desktop to the cloud and back. We then expose APIs so you can see the status or activity that was synced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Quickbooks Destop, by default only the current Fiscal year transactions are displayed. Could you try changing the Date filter to "All", to see if the Sales Order made it ?

Comment: I didn't even notice that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So your Request is succeeding but you are not seeing it in QuicKBooks after sync is run.
Check the sync status of the object, or you can see all the sync activity by calling these APIS

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncActivity

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

Even though your request succeeded, before it can by synced to QuickBooks it must pass the business rules to be created/updated on the desktop.

If your object encountered an error (lets say it was a duplicate) then you can add an errored object filter on your query to query for it as well.

regards
Jarred

Comment: Thanks Jarred, can you clue me in on how this could be done via PHP DevKit?  I've also posted the proper request/response in my question.

Comment: I'm not very well versed in PHP, only .Net and Java. Sorry

Comment: I edited the question based on findings from your suggestions.